# R plot set scale

Tags: r, data-visualization

I did some research and didn't find what I was looking for: I have a data set x = 10,100,1000 and y1, y2, y3 respectively, and I want to plot those points.

But what is happening is that in the x axis the values that are appearing are 10, 200, 400, 600, 800 and 1000. How can I set the scale so that it only appears the values I specified above? What I'm doing is:

```
y_values <- c(9, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8)
x_values <- c(10,100,1000)
plot(x_values, y_values)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you noticed that you have **4** `y_values`, but only **3** `x_values`?

Comment: The way to do this is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3785089/1217536).

Comment: Since this question is only about how to do this in R, it is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). For future reference, this Q could be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), however, it will be off-topic there as well, since the answer already exists (as noted above).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use software.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to set axes=F, in the plot, the use the low-level axis function:

```
plot(x_values, y_values, axes=F)
axis(2)
axis(1, at=x_values, labels=as.character(x_values))
```